# Adding multiple views of same entity in sitemap in Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, powerapps-modeldriven, model-driven-app

Is it possible to add multiple views of same entity in the Site Map(left navigation) in Dynamics 365. I need to add the default view as well as filtered view of Project entity on Left navigation. I have seen an option to add it as url instead of entity. Is there any other way to add multiple view of same entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can add the direct url addressable view link in sitemap. One for default view (maybe entity itself) and another for filtered view. This is the closest solution we tried in one of the implementation. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/open-forms-views-dialogs-reports-url?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422#display-a-view-in-the-application-navigation-using-the-site-map)

```
Url="/main.aspx?appid=e2bc1066-488f-eb11-b1ac-000d3a56ead9&pagetype=entitylist&etn=account&viewid=%7b<GUID value of view id>%7d"
```

Alternate approach from the community using web resource can be found [here](https://community.dynamics.com/365/sales/f/dynamics-365-for-sales-forum/418440/show-specific-view-in-sitemap).

Comment: In this case I need to change the appid and viewid, if I am moving the solution to a different environment right? Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: @Reshma unless you create the app and view individually in each environment (dev, qa) the same guid will be maintained while deploying thru alm solutions